# How to identify health check request?

Tags: actions-on-google

My app is getting health check about 10 health check request per hour, and that makes my conversation log messy.
Because of the health check does not have screen capability, our backend server response the request as Google Home is requesting.

Is there any way to detect if the request is health check request or not?

Comment: Are you sure the requests you're getting are health checks from the Assistant store? If so, can you share the request logs so we can search for a way to identify them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you *should* be responding as if it was a Google Home. You have to respond with valid output, or it will reject you. So don't try to be too fancy in your response - just use this to avoid cluttering your analytics and logs.

The [health check](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/actions-health-check) will look like a normal welcome request. The ping will contain an argument named `is_health_check` with a `boolValue` of true and a `textValue` of 1. If you're using Dialogflow, this will be one of the arguments at `originalRequest.data.inputs[0]`. For the Actions SDK, it will be at `data.inputs[0]`.

Here is a partial sample from Dialogflow:

```
{
    "originalRequest": {
        "source": "google",
        "version": "2",
        "data": {
            "surface": {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "rawInputs": [
                        {
                            "query": "Sample",
                            "inputType": "VOICE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "arguments": [
                        {
                            "textValue": "1",
                            "name": "is_health_check",
                            "boolValue": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN"
                }
            ],
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Prisoner! I will return same json response as when Google Home is sending a request, I just wanted to identify if the access is from health check or not and avoid sending conversation log to my logging infrastructure. Thanks!